# Gamma reflection formula for large z

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

In an expression involving many gamma functions I have a $\frac{1}{\Gamma(-z)}$ where $z\gg 1$. I need to use Stirling formula to approximate this expression. Can I use the following formula?
$$\Gamma(z) \, \Gamma(1 − z) = \pi \,  
\sin (\pi z) $$

Answer (score 2):

Why not? The [reciprocal gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function) is entire and thus "well behaved".
The [Euler reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) on the other side should be :
$$\Gamma(z) \, \Gamma(1 − z) = \frac {\pi}{\sin (\pi z)}$$
so that using $\;\Gamma(1-z)=-z\,\Gamma(-z)\,$ you get :
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(-z)}=-\frac{z}{\pi}\,\Gamma(z)\sin (\pi z)$$
and may apply Stirling...

Comment: Long time no speak ! Cheers  :-)

Comment: @Claude: well gamma radiates! Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The reflection formula is valid for all $z$ and may be rewritten as
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(-z)} = -\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\Gamma(1+z).
$$
However, note that in your case, if you use Strirling approximation, you might be considering integer $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(-z)} \equiv 0.$$

Comment: No, $z$ is real not integer.